# Perfino agent logging

Tags: perfino

Can the logger used by the perfino agent be configured? We would like to control the maximum size of the file.

Our agent is currently configured like so:

javaagent:/usr/local/lib/perfino/perfino.jar=server=perfino.env,name=${HSTNAMESHORT}-${APPNAME},group=${ENV}/${HSTNAMESHORT},logMBean=10,logFile=${LOG_DIR}/perfinologs/${HSTNAMESHORT}-${APPNAME}.log"

Thanks!

Comment: There is no maximum file size feature for the log file. I see you have added logMBean=10 to enabled more logging for the MBean subsystem, is that what is generating too much information in the log file or something else?

Comment: I must confess I don't know what logMBean=10 does. We're getting 100's of warnings every 10 seconds similar to the below.

mbean> [Tue May 17 13:25:25 AEST 2022] metrics:name=com.x.y.z.CqEventSubscriber.PanicResponse,type=timers not found

Presumably we're getting the warnings because we're telling Perfino to chart custom metrics that are not available.

Comment: So what happens if you remove logMBean=10?